# OnCompletion Listener

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a music player application.

I would like to automatically play the next song as soon as the current song finish playing. Right now the code I currently have (Below) sort of works, but not perfectly.........It plays the next song, but as soon as that song finish playing, it stops, it doesn't go to the next.

Also here is what I have so far!

Code:

```
boolean shuffle = false;

mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if (!shuffle) {
                    Random random = new Random();
                    position = random.nextInt(songs_List.size());
                } else {
                    if (position++ > songs_List.size() - 1) {
                        position = 0;
                    } else {
                        position += 1;
                    }
                }
                create();
                BroadCast_UpdatePlaying_song();
                updateSeekBar();
            }
        });


private void create() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(songs_List.get(position).getPath()));
        if (RequestAudioFocus()) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } else {
            stopSelf();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Another app is currently playing audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Implementing a completion listener is the right way to do this -- well, it's a way that works for me, anyway. I don't think there's any way to tell what's going on, from the code snippet provided. What does `create()` do here, for example? You might need to put some logging in, to check what calculations are being performed.

Comment: Hey there! I added the "create" function. Can you take another look please?

Comment: Not sure - there's nothing that stands out as wrong. I'm not sure that repeated calls to `MediaPlayer.create()` are necessary -- to start the next track I would call `reset()`, `setDataSource()`, `prepare()`, and `start()`. But that doesn't mean your way is wrong. I'd suggest you need to put some additional logging in, and monitor exactly what's going on. If it's any help, you can see the code I usually use in this example: https://github.com/kevinboone/androidmusicserver/blob/master/src/net/kevinboone/androidmusicplayer/Player.java.

Comment: not completely related but your shuffle code is wrong ;) should be if (shuffle)

Comment: Thank you Toofy!

Comment: Thank you @kevinBoone I will look at your example! I highly appreciate your help!